# How to create an ID2D1Bitmap from a Pixel Array

Tags: c++, bitmap, raycasting, direct2d

I'm trying to create a Raycaster with DirectX, and I need to be able to draw each frame pixel by pixel.  The way I'm trying to do that is by creating an array of pixels and then turning that array into a bitmap to then display on the window.  However, I can't figure out how to do that.

In a past version that just used the standard Win32 API without DirectX, I've used the method from here: [How to display pixels on screen directly from a raw array of RGB values faster than SetPixel()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005744/how-to-display-pixels-on-screen-directly-from-a-raw-array-of-rgb-values-faster-t)

However, that doesn't seem to be working anymore now that I'm using DirectX.  In fact, none of the Win32 drawing commands (such as `Rectangle`) are working.  Only DirectX commands are working (I guess because I'm using `PeekMessage` instead of `GetMessage` and am not waiting for the `WM_PAINT` message).

So it seems that I need to find a DirectX equivalent of that stackoverflow answer.  The closest answer I could find to my problem is answered here: [How to efficiently write pixels to the screen with Direct2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814610/how-to-efficiently-write-pixels-to-the-screen-with-direct2d), but I can't figure out how to use `ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmap()`.  It's probably really simple, but I'm new to DirectX, and I couldn't find any examples on how to do this.  So probably all I need is a comprehensive example about how to use `CreateBitmap` and `DrawBitmap` to create and draw a bitmap from an array.

My main program is mostly based off this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p91FvlnyOyo&list=PLKK11Ligqitij8r6hd6tfqqesh3T_xWJA&index=1

The `GameEngine` class controls and handles the different scenes.  Each scene inherits from a `GameScene` class.  The `GameScene` class has a pointer to an instance of my `Graphics` class which just interacts with DirectX and has shortcut functions so that I can just call `Graphics.DrawCircle(...)` for example instead of using DirectX.  The `Graphics.SetPixels(SomeType array, int width, int height)` is the function I'm trying to figure out.

Here's the function I'm trying to work on.  It has the code from the old version that was working with the Win32 API but not with DirectX:

```
void Graphics::SetPixels(COLORREF * arr, int width, int height)
{

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // Create the bitmap and draw it on the screen
    HBITMAP map = CreateBitmap(
        width, // width. 512 in my case
        height, // height
        1, // Color Planes, unfortanutelly don't know what is it actually. Let it be 1
        8 * 4, // Size of memory for one pixel in bits (in win32 4 bytes = 4*8 bits)
        (void*)arr); // pointer to array
    // Temp HDC to copy picture
    HDC src = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // hdc - Device context for window, I've got earlier with GetDC(hWnd) or GetDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(src, map); // Inserting picture into our temp HDC
    // Copy image from temp HDC to window
    BitBlt(hdc, // Destination
        10,  // x and
        10,  // y - upper-left corner of place, where we'd like to copy
        width, // width of the region
        height, // height
        src, // source
        0,   // x and
        0,   // y of upper left corner  of part of the source, from where we'd like to copy
        SRCCOPY); // Defined DWORD to juct copy pixels. Watch more on msdn;


    DeleteDC(src); // Deleting temp HDC

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

}
```

Here's the function that renders everything

```
void RaycasterScene1::Render()
{
    GameScene::gfx->BeginDraw(); // This just does renderTarget->BegingDraw()
    int width = 100, height = 100;
    COLORREF * arr = (COLORREF*)calloc(width * height, sizeof(COLORREF));
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) { arr[i] = RGB(255, 0, 0); }
    GameScene::gfx->SetPixels(arr, width, height);
    GameScene::gfx->EndDraw();
}
```

Here's my `main.cpp`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "GameEngine.h"

Graphics* graphics;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(...)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        GameEngine::KeyDown(wParam);
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:
        GameEngine::KeyUp(wParam);
        break;
    }

    // Otherwse, use the default window behavior
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(...)
{
    // Set up window class
    //...

    // The Graphics class is from my Graphics.h file
    graphics = new Graphics();
    if (!graphics->Init(windowhandle))
    {
        delete graphics;
        return -1;
    }

        // The GameScene class is from one of my files
    GameScene::Init(graphics);

    ShowWindow(windowhandle, nCmdShow);

        // RaycasterScene1 is child class of GameScene
    RaycasterScene1 scene;
        // GameEngine is from one of my files
    GameEngine::SetLevel(&scene);

    MSG message;
    message.message = WM_NULL;

    while (message.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
                // GameEngine::Run() calls RaycasterScene1::Run() which calls RaycasterScene1::Render() which will eventually call Camera::Render() but currently just tries setting up a pixel array to draw with Graphics::SetPixels()
        GameEngine::Run();

        if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            DispatchMessage(&message);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I include the `BeginDraw()` and `EndDraw()` functions in the funciton that renders everything, all I get is a black window.  If I take them away, all I get is a blank, white window.

If the problem is something other than the `SetPixels` function, please let me know, though I'd still like to know how to do the `SetPixels` function with DirectX.

Comment: If you use a swapchain with your window, or HWND D2D target, don't mess with regular user32 methods to draw to it. If you want to use memory copy to update D2D content, you can map backbuffer surface, ID2D1Bitmap objects also offer memory mapping functionality.